# 2 players Tic Tac toe game

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to make a two player tic-tac-toe game. When the first player clicks the OnClick method with mark X on the button, but I stuck - I don't know how to make the onClick() to detect when the 2nd player clicked and how to mark O on the button ..plz help.. My .java is below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setBoard();
    }
    int c[][];
    int i, j, k = 0;
    Button b[][];
    TextView textView;

    private void setBoard() {

        b = new Button[4][4];
        c = new int[4][4];


        // Button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newgame);


        b[1][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        b[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        b[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);


        b[2][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        b[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        b[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);


        b[3][3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        b[3][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        b[3][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
                c[i][j] = 2;
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                b[i][j].setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(i, j));
                if (!b[i][j].isEnabled()) {
                    b[i][j].setText("o");
                    b[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
            int x;
            int y;


            public MyClickListener(int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }


            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (b[x][y].isEnabled()) {
                    b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    b[x][y].setText("X");
                    c[x][y] = 0;
                    textView.setText("");
//WHAT NEXT




                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add a new variable

```
int playerTurn;
```

which should initially be set to 1. On the first onClick() execution, the value of playerTurn is 1, so place an X, and change the playerTurn to 2. On the second click, when you check the value of playerTurn, you will place an O, and change its value to 1. And this keep on going.

```
int player = 1;
public void onClick(View view){ 
    if (b[x][y].isEnabled() { 
        b[x][y].setEnabled(false); 
        if (player == 1){ 
            b[x][y].setText("X"); 
            c[x][y] = 0; 
            player = 1; 
        } else {
            b[x][y].setText("O"); 
            c[x][y] = 1; 
            player = 2; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i got it thankyou very much ...i will try tht now ..ChEERS

Comment: This is what i did is it ok

Comment: 'int player=1;
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (b[x][y].isEnabled()&& player==1)
                {
                    b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    b[x][y].setText("X");
                    c[x][y] = 0;
                    player=0;
                    textView.setText("");
                 }else
                {
                    b[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    b[x][y].setText("O");
                    c[x][y]=1;
                    player=1;
                }
                }
            }'

Comment: It was hard to read your comment with source code. I edited my answer, including your comment with some fixes. Only part I am missing is:

c[x][y]=1; 
c[x][y]=0;

Comment: those are for checkin who is winning....i set the so tht i can check if X won or O won ..hope im correct ..my emulator is now working right now so i cant test it ..im waiting downloading the emulator again ...

Comment: You are very helpfull ...this is my first time posting problem online ...and its helped me ...thankyou very much ...im sure i will have more problems to post LOL and i will surely do it here...

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a boolean to detetct the click. Say a boolean `isFirstPlayerTurn` is true when button is clicked first time. Make it false for second turn. Do this for all turns and you will know which player is clicking the button.
Example:

```
private boolean isFirstPlayerTurn = true;
```

...

```
void onclick() {
        if (isFirstPlayerTurn) {
            // clicked by player 1
            isFirstPlayerTurn = false;
        } else {
            // clicked by player 2
            isFirstPlayerTurn = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do i need to use wht u suggested in the onClick() itself?

Comment: I have added an example for your needs.

Comment: which means i need to add variable for both players and base on their an X or a O will be placed.

Comment: One variable will be enough for both. The example I provided clearly states that you need to alter the variable for both players.

Comment: ok thanks ..i will try it now ...im new to android and java and its very confusing